# How to find shortest negative cycle after running Bellman Ford if the weight of one edge changes?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, bellman-ford

Say one runs the Bellman Ford algorithm on a graph, and stores the `distance_to` and `predecessor_to` dictionaries. If only one edge weight changes, is it possible to test for negative cycles without running the Bellman-Ford algorithm again?

Comment: Strictly speaking, no (I think). A single edge weight can change the shortest path from your source vertex to many (albeit not all) other vertices. Your `distance_to` and `predecessor_to` relationships have potentially changed in non-trivial ways (and you would need (V-1)E computations to prove that they haven't). If your network has a special structure (e.g. very modular) you may be able to isolate the changes to a specific vertex subset, in which case only some relationships may have changes (and you know a-priori which those might be).